# is month between month1 and month2

Tags: mysql

I want to search whether selected month is in between months;

for example:

- jan-2011 is between jan-2011 and march-2011
- apr-2011 is not between feb-2011 and march-2011

how do I select only if selected month-year is between month1 and month2 in mysql?

both month1 and month 2 are using datetime data type.

Comment: How are you storing those months/years in the database?

Comment: column 1(month1) and column 2(month2) are in datetime format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct a Date for each and then use the "BETWEEN" clause in your query.

i.e.
select * from table where datecolumn between "01/01/2001" and "03/01/2001".

Comment: When using dates within MySQL, remember to use the format "2011-01-01" rather than "01/01/2011"...

Comment: Yeah - only Americans use month-day-year. It's a completely retarded format; either use small-medium-large or large-medium-small, but not medium-small-large. Learn to code using standard (ISO) date format yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: mysql coding is Y-m-d... if anything it's more work for america to convert to their format.  Don't see where this american-hatred has any point in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Lo and behold.. the mighty manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: I'm searching for valid whole day in a month between two date

Comment: not sure what you're saying there.  In your post you said you're using datetime - between should work for date time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECt * FROM table WHERE ( MONTH(a_date) > 1 AND MONTH(a_date) < 4 )
                       AND YEAR(a_date) = 2011 -- BETWEAN 01 AND 04  2011
```

---

```
$e = 'jan-2011';
$e = explode('-',$e);

$month = $e[0];
$year = $e[1];
```

---

```
SELECt * FROM table WHERE  a_date 
BETWEEN  STR_TO_DATE('jan/01/2010','%M/%d/%Y')  
AND STR_TO_DATE('march/01/2010','%M/%d/%Y')
```

---

```
SELECt * FROM table WHERE  a_date 
BETWEEN  STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2010','%m/%d/%Y')  
AND STR_TO_DATE('03/01/2010','%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: This answer seems okay, but what for are the 2 query string below ?

Comment: table AS t1 Union ( ANOTHER query FROM with t.1  )